# Duplicating data from my tableview according to a number the user chose

Tags: swift, xcode, input, tableview

I am currently working on a workout interval timer app and the last thing I want to implement is the ability for the user to choose the amount of sets they wish to do and then use that number to duplicate the exercises already entered so that the user does not have to enter the same exercises multiple times. I have already implemented a way for the user to input the amount of sets they wish to do. The problem I am facing is that I do not know how to get the tableview data and duplicate by however many times the user wants to(the amount of sets they want to do). the tableview and amount of sets input are in two different viewcontrollers.

Comment: You have to pass that information between the controllers. Pass on the sets count when you navigate from sets view controller to tableviewcontroller. Show the data accordingly.

Comment: Hi sorry I am relatively new to Xcode and am not sure on how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please follow this article. The author has explained it in detail. Perfect for the beginners. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers